# Why won't polymer's flex attribute/class just work?

Tags: polymer, flexbox, polymer-1.0

Browser: Firefox v35 OS: Linux Ubuntu 14, Polymer: v1.4

Was following Rob Dodson's polycasts - most of the videos mention using 'flex' (flexbox) to achieve responsive designs. I however have had a rough time getting it to work..

In the sample file listed below,

- the flex attribute on the paper-header-panel is superflous (even without it, the element stretches - note the blue border
- the flex attribute on the span tag within the toolbar DOES work - see the more icon scoot all the way to the right. This is good / expected
- Finally I'd like the div with the content class to 'flex' - but it won't. Ideally there should be no white area.

[image: Un flexing]

The documentation & [guide](https://elements.polymer-project.org/guides/responsive-material-design-layouts) isn't helping a bit. Even the snippets on the guide are not working for me.

Code follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>

<link rel='import' href='elements.html' />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
<style>
    .icon-snooze {
        color: red;
        width: 48px;
        height: 48px;
    }
</style>


<style is="custom-style" include='iron-flex iron-positioning'>
    body {
        border: 1px dashed red;
    }
    
    paper-header-panel {
        border: 2px dashed dodgerblue;
    }
    
    .content {
        border: 2px dashed tomato;
        background-color: var(--paper-light-blue-500);
    }
</style>

</head>

<body class='fullbleed vertical layout'>

<paper-header-panel class='flex'>
    <paper-toolbar>
        <paper-icon-button id="navicon" icon="icons:menu"></paper-icon-button>
        <div>Header</div>
        <span class='flex'></span>
        <paper-icon-button id='morebutton' icon='icons:more-vert'></paper-icon-button>

    </paper-toolbar>
    <div class='content flex'>Content </div>

</paper-header-panel>
</body>
</html>
```

---

More observations:
Horizontal flex works as expected/out of the box.

> For the vertical flex, it works if I set **an explicit height on the parent/container** - which kinda defeats the purpose.

```html
<body class='fullbleed vertical layout'>
<div class='layout vertical container' style='height:50vh;' >
    <div>one</div>
    <div class="flex">two (won't flex without height set)</div>
    <div>three</div>
</div>
<div class='layout horizontal container'>
    <div>one</div>
    <div class="flex">two (will flex)</div>
    <div>three</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: JFYI - I've included iron-flex-layout-classes.html in my elements.html ...included in snippet

Comment: Bear in mind that the classes approach to `iron-flex-layout` uses the `/deep/` combinator which [is being deprecated](https://blog.polymer-project.org/announcements/2015/12/01/deprecating-deep/). You should use the mixins in `iron-flex-layout.html` instead

Comment: @Alan - Are you sure about this ? From the iron-flex-layout.html code comments: Please note that the old [/deep/ layout classes](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-flex-layout/tree/master/classes)
are deprecated, and should not be used. To continue using layout properties
directly in markup, please switch to using the new `dom-module`-based
[layout classes](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-flex-layout/tree/master/iron-flex-layout-classes.html).

Comment: The `iron-flex-layout-classes.html` found in the `iron-flex-layout` github root is the correct file to use.

Comment: @Gishu yeah, you're right, I thought the `iron-flex-layout-classes.html` file was still using the old classes model but as you mentioned it's not doing so

Answer (score 1):

`iron-flex-layout` can be a hard one to use at the beginning and even later down the road.

Let's breakdown how we can achive the desired output.
First we need that `fullbleed` class on the body. That makes it so we are using the full size of the screen. Then we add the `<paper-header-panel>` element that will take care of displaying, positioning and sizing of our header and content. We don't need to add any classes to the `paper-header-panel`.
Next we add in two `div` elements. Other is the actual header with the `paper-header` class and other is the content host with `fit` class. The `fit` class takes care of making sure that our content fills the whole screen.

Inside of the first div with `paper-header` class we add in our toolbar and other content just as you had provided. That works and is correct.

If you would like to have different layout type for your content (`horizontal` or `vertical` for example) you can add the needed classess to the div with the `fit` class.

See the code below.

```html
<!doctype html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!---- >
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
  Toggle below/above as backup when server is down
  <!---->
  <base href="https://polygit2.appspot.com/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-header-panel/paper-header-panel.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-toolbar/paper-toolbar.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-icon/iron-icon.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout-classes.html">

  <style is="custom-style" include='iron-flex iron-positioning'>
    body {
      border: 1px dashed red;
    }
    paper-header-panel {
      border: 2px dashed dodgerblue;
    }
    .fit {
      @apply(--iron-positoning-fit);
      height: 100%;
      border: 2px dashed tomato;
      background-color: #00B7FF;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body class='fullbleed'>
  <paper-header-panel>
    <div class="paper-header">
      <paper-toolbar>
        <paper-icon-button id="navicon" icon="icons:menu"></paper-icon-button>
        <div>Header</div>
        <span class="flex"></span>
        <paper-icon-button id='morebutton' icon='icons:more-vert'></paper-icon-button>
      </paper-toolbar>
    </div>
    <div class="fit">
      <div>Content</div>
    </div>
  </paper-header-panel>
</body>
```

Comment: Yeah i got this to work with fit yesterday - but fit uses absolute positioning.. Should i be concerned about that ?

Comment: On my use cases fit hasn't caused any problems. More than likely you are okay using it. So no real need to worry. If you check the sources of paper-elements many of them use absolute positioning.