# Polymer flex span doesn't work

Tags: polymer, flexbox

I have been trying to follow the Polymer tutorial [here](https://elements.polymer-project.org/guides/responsive-material-design-layouts), but the icons part doesn't work for me.

The relevant code is

```
<body class="fullbleed vertical layout">
  <paper-header-panel class="flex">
    <paper-toolbar>
      <div>Header</div>
      <span class="flex"></span>
      <paper-icon-button icon="search"></paper-icon-button>
    </paper-toolbar>
    <div>Content</div>
  </paper-header-panel>
</body>
```

The flex span in the middle is supposed to push the search icon all the way to the right, but it doesn't work at all for me. The icon shows up immediately after the text, like this

[image]

I am using Chrome 52 on Ubuntu. The closest question I could find to my problem is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36841156/why-wont-polymers-flex-attribute-class-just-work), but they report that the span does work for them (on Firefox 35).

Note, here are my imports. I've got a bunch of extra imports for other paper components, but that shouldn't matter.

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-card/paper-card.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-listbox/paper-listbox.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-item/paper-item.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-drawer-panel/paper-drawer-panel.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-header-panel/paper-header-panel.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-toolbar/paper-toolbar.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout.html">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware that polymer recently changed how you deal with classes (rather than use @apply in your css.)

You are not showing your complete template, but the style tag should have an include for the bits of iron flex you want.  Rather than repeat it all here, its at the beginning of this document.

https://elements.polymer-project.org/guides/flex-layout

But you have to import the classes rather than the layout

`<link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout-classes.html">`

and use the appropriate includes in your style sheet

`<style include="iron-flex iron-flex-alignment">`

Comment: Thanks, importing iron-flex-layout-classes and adding the style include inside my template fixed everything.